# Debugging in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: debugging, scala, intellij-idea

I'm working with a Scala application. Unlike Visual Studio, IntelliJ 12 doesn't stop at exceptions by default, it just exists from debugging. And I can't go inside some parts of code such as anonymous functions, can't evaluate some expressions or variables due to its saying "dynamic expressions can't be evaluated" and so on.

I'd like to be able to do all of that. How?

Comment: I recall seeing this in the plugin release notes, but I imagine it only works in IDEA 13.  I agree it's a major pain point for developing in Scala, and I hope if it's not supported in 13, that Java 8 will make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit break points ("View breakpoints") in the debugger. It allows you to add exception breakpoints, you may say pause on any type of exception. So this does work when you enable it. Second, with "Force Step Into" you can go into any function if necessary.

The third item I have no clue what you actually mean, as I have never used Visual Studio. Perhaps you can elaborate what dynamic-expressions would be.